# tabularray: Using \fakeverb in the cmd argument

Tags: verbatim, tabularray

I have a table with cells that include characters which I want to treat as verbatim.  [Section 6.2 of the `tabularray` documentation](https://ctan.mirror.globo.tech/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) states that we can wrap the contents of cells in `\fakeverb{}` to achieve that.

Instead of modifying every cell, I would like to use the `cmd` or `font` arguments in `colspec` to specify that every entry in a column should be treated as verbatim. How do I achieve this in this simple case?

Compiling a table like this:

```latex
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[cmd=\fakeverb]}}
a \\
a_b \\
d$c \\
\end{tblr}
```

Generates errors like this:

```latex
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...Vn\cs_end: \l__tblr_b_tl {\fakeverb 
                                                  }
l.353 \end
          {tblr}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\fakeverb` is provided by the [codehigh](https://ctan.org/pkg/codehigh) package. By loading this package, the example works.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{codehigh}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[cmd=\fakeverb]}}
a \\
a_b \\
d$c \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. I accepted the answer because you are right that this works. Turns out the issue is that I was using an old TeX distribution. Updating fixed everything.